# How to add concrete type annotations for np.recarray?

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I have the following code in a file `scratch.py`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_array(arr: np.recarray) -> None:
    print(arr.x)

my_array(np.rec.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')]))
```

Running `mypy scratch.py  --disallow-any-generics` gives the following error:

```
scratch.py:3: error: Missing type parameters for generic type "recarray"  [type-arg]
```

However, the following code gets rid of the error above:

```
def my_array(arr: np.recarray[Any, Any]) -> None:
    print(arr.x)
```

but I would prefer more specific types like:

```
def my_array(arr: np.recarray[np.dtype[[('x', float), ('y', int)]]]) -> None:
    print(arr.x)
```

but I haven't figured out how to do this correctly.

```
from typing import Union

import numpy as np

def my_array(arr: np.recarray[Union[float, int], np.dtype[Union[np.float_, np.int_]]]) -> None:
    print(arr.x)

my_array(np.rec.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')]))
```

Passes the check but i don't know why.

Comment: I  don't know if makes a difference in specifying the compound dtype, but `recarray` is just a subclass of `ndarray`, one that lets you acceccess fields as attributes.  `np.array([(1,2),(3,4)], dtype=[...])` is enough.

Comment: While recarrays and structured arrays have part of numpy for a long time, `typing` is a relatively new and evolving feature.  https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html

Comment: Since the dtype of of a structured array has to be defined explicitly during the array creation, I wonder if there's much value in adding the extra layer of dtype checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Union

import numpy as np

def my_array(arr: np.recarray[Union[float, int], np.dtype[Union[np.float_, np.int_]]]) -> None:
    print(arr.x)

my_array(np.rec.array([(1.0, 2), (3.0, 4)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<i8')]))
```

Works.

Comment: You better explain why it "works".

Comment: I can't.  I've just edited my question to ask about how this works as well.